# Unable to cache files in .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to add expired headers to my .htaccess file and these files will not cache my .htaccess file is below. What am i doing wrong? My .htaccess file is in my root directory, do i need to add a .htaccess file in these subdirectories?

https://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css?x93196 (1 hour)
https://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css?x93196 (1 hour)
https://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css?x93196 (1 hour)

### EXPIRES CACHING

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
```

# CSS

```
ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"
```

# Data interchange

```
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/geo+json                  "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/calendar                         "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"
```

# Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images

```
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 year"
```

# HTML

```
ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"
```

# JavaScript

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"
```

# Manifest files

```
ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"
```

# Markdown

```
ExpiresByType text/markdown                         "access plus 0 seconds"
```

# Media files

```
ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"
```

# WebAssembly

```
ExpiresByType application/wasm                      "access plus 1 year"
```

# Web fonts

```
# Collection
ExpiresByType font/collection                       "access plus 1 month"

# Embedded OpenType (EOT)
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

# OpenType
ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/otf                              "access plus 1 month"

# TrueType
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/ttf                              "access plus 1 month"

# Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

# Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/woff2                            "access plus 1 month"
```

# Other

```
ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"
```